# Modifing the desktop of an apple device by code it is posible?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

i was wondering if there is a way trough code to modify the look of the desktop of for example the iphone i mean do what you do manually that of grouping all the social applications like facebook , twitter etcc in a folder , theres a way of doing that by code?

Comment: Nope, not without jailbreaking.

Comment: only works with jailbraking ? but if i have it then how would i do to do what i want?